# How to Return rows of XML Nested Nodes as a string separated by a Comma (,) character

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Need help to with a query below to return rows of following XML nested nodes. Some of column's data require to return multiple values (as exist in XML script) with comma separated e.g. nodes 'BillType', 'BillNumber', 'CONTAINER_NUMBER' or 'CONTAINER_STATUS' etc..

Thanks in Advance.

XML...

```
DECLARE @xml xml  
set @xml = N'<declaration xmlns="http://xyz.IND/NCCS/v2">
  <identification>77988324</identification>
  <type>I10</type>
  <functionalReference>IM15_262053</functionalReference>
  <transactionType>9</transactionType>
  <totalGrossMass>
    <quantity>992</quantity>
    <unitOfMeasurement>KGM</unitOfMeasurement>
  </totalGrossMass>
  <jurisdiction>
    <importDate>20150822</importDate>
  </jurisdiction>
  <submitter>
    <identifier>40063605C</identifier>
  </submitter>
  <permit>
    <authority>DOC</authority>
    <number>12345</number>
    <sequence>1</sequence>
  </permit>
  <permit>
    <authority>LTS</authority>
    <number>4321</number>
    <sequence>2</sequence>
  </permit>
  <permit>
    <authority>AF1</authority>
    <number>43253445</number>
    <sequence>3</sequence>
  </permit>
  <additionalDocument>
    <type>CER</type>
    <identifier>cer1</identifier>
    <sequence>4</sequence>
  </additionalDocument>
  <additionalDocument>
    <type>PP</type>
    <identifier>pp1</identifier>
    <sequence>5</sequence>
  </additionalDocument>
  <additionalInformation>
    <code>AWC</code>
    <type>OIN</type>
    <sequence>5</sequence>
  </additionalInformation>
  <additionalInformation>
    <code>CGO</code>
    <type>OIN</type>
    <sequence>6</sequence>
  </additionalInformation>
  <additionalInformation>
    <code>DIP</code>
    <type>OIN</type>
    <sequence>7</sequence>
  </additionalInformation>
  <additionalInformationALP>
    <text>PLEASE LET IT PASS</text>
    <code>Y</code>
    <sequence>1</sequence>
  </additionalInformationALP>
  <additionalInformationHAN>
    <text>HANDLE</text>
    <sequence>3</sequence>
  </additionalInformationHAN>
  <additionalInformationMAC>
    <accountNumber>123456</accountNumber>
    <accountName>Name</accountName>
    <sequence>4</sequence>
  </additionalInformationMAC>
  <agent>
    <identifier>40063605C</identifier>
    <roleCode>CB</roleCode>
  </agent>
  <approvedEstablishmentPlace>
    <identifier>7129D</identifier>
  </approvedEstablishmentPlace>
  <approvedEstablishmentPlace>
    <identifier>7174K</identifier>
  </approvedEstablishmentPlace>
  <borderTransportMeans>
    <identifier>VHQZ123</identifier>
    <name>S.S. KUMAR</name>
    <transportModeCode>1</transportModeCode>
    <voyageNumber>138</voyageNumber>
  </borderTransportMeans>
  <carrier>
    <name>IND CARRIER</name>
  </carrier>
  <currencyExchange>
    <rateOfExchange>
      <value>1.2</value>
      <sequence>1</sequence>
    </rateOfExchange>
    <currencyCode>AUD</currencyCode>
  </currencyExchange>
  <currencyExchange>
    <rateOfExchange>
      <value>2.3</value>
      <sequence>2</sequence>
    </rateOfExchange>
    <currencyCode>USD</currencyCode>
  </currencyExchange>
  <paymentMethod>
    <paymentMethodCode>C</paymentMethodCode>
    <sequence>1</sequence>
  </paymentMethod>
  <dutyTaxFee>
    <amount>3</amount>
    <currencyCode>AU</currencyCode>
    <typeCode>ADD</typeCode>
    <sequence>2</sequence>
  </dutyTaxFee>
  <GST>
    <amount>1</amount>
    <currencyCode>AU</currencyCode>
    <sequence>4</sequence>
  </GST>
  <tariffDuty>
    <amount>2</amount>
    <currencyCode>AU</currencyCode>
    <sequence>3</sequence>
  </tariffDuty>
  <totalAmount>
    <amount>6</amount>
    <currencyCode>AU</currencyCode>
    <sequence>5</sequence>
  </totalAmount>
  <goodsShipment>
    <exportationCountryCode>AU</exportationCountryCode>
    <transactionNatureCode>41</transactionNatureCode>
    <consignment>
      <loadingLocation>AUQBE</loadingLocation>
      <bill>
        <identifier>MB1</identifier>
        <type>MB</type>
      </bill>
      <bill>
        <identifier>HB1</identifier>
        <type>BM</type>
        <container>
          <identifier>ABC128021</identifier>
          <sequence>1</sequence>
          <packageSequence>1</packageSequence>
        </container>
      </bill>
      <bill>
        <identifier>HB2</identifier>
        <type>BM</type>
        <container>
          <identifier>CSCU7549505</identifier>
          <sequence>2</sequence>
          <packageSequence>3</packageSequence>
          <packageSequence>4</packageSequence>
        </container>
        <packageSequence>2</packageSequence>
      </bill>
      <transportEquipment>
        <sequence>1</sequence>
        <additionalInformationMAS>
          <approvedSystemNumber>123456</approvedSystemNumber>
          <sequence>2</sequence>
        </additionalInformationMAS>
        <additionalInformationMCD>
          <answers>YNYNY</answers>
          <sequence>1</sequence>
        </additionalInformationMCD>
        <characteristicsCode>45</characteristicsCode>
        <fullness>4</fullness>
        <identifier>ABC128021</identifier>
        <seal>
          <sequence>1</sequence>
          <identifier>seal1</identifier>
        </seal>
        <seal>
          <sequence>2</sequence>
          <identifier>seal2</identifier>
        </seal>
        <containerPackLocation>
          <name>1</name>
        </containerPackLocation>
      </transportEquipment>
      <transportEquipment>
        <sequence>2</sequence>
        <additionalInformationMAS>
          <approvedSystemNumber>987456</approvedSystemNumber>
          <sequence>4</sequence>
        </additionalInformationMAS>
        <additionalInformationMCD>
          <answers>YYNNN</answers>
          <sequence>3</sequence>
        </additionalInformationMCD>
        <characteristicsCode>43</characteristicsCode>
        <fullness>5</fullness>
        <identifier>CSCU7549505</identifier>
        <seal>
          <sequence>1</sequence>
          <identifier>seal22</identifier>
        </seal>
        <seal>
          <sequence>2</sequence>
          <identifier>seal23</identifier>
        </seal>
      </transportEquipment>
      <unloadingLocation>
        <identifier>AUSYD</identifier>
      </unloadingLocation>
    </consignment>
    <freightCharge>
      <amount>12</amount>
      <currencyCode>AU</currencyCode>
      <apportionmentCode>160</apportionmentCode>
    </freightCharge>
    <deliveryDestination>
      <name>ACME DELIVERY</name>
      <address>
        <city>dtp</city>
        <countryCode>AU</countryCode>
        <line>dtp</line>
        <postcode>2500</postcode>
      </address>
    </deliveryDestination>
    <governmentAgencyGoodsItem>
      <sequence>1</sequence>
      <customsValue>
        <amount>1</amount>
        <currencyCode>AU</currencyCode>
      </customsValue>
      <permit>
        <authority>MOH</authority>
        <number>ga2</number>
        <sequence>2</sequence>
      </permit>
      <additionalInformation>
        <code>CGO</code>
        <type>OIN</type>
        <sequence>6</sequence>
      </additionalInformation>
      <additionalInformationPRO>
        <code>BEF</code>
        <sequence>4</sequence>
      </additionalInformationPRO>
      <additionalInformationREL>
        <relationshipIndicatorCode>135</relationshipIndicatorCode>
        <supplierSequence>1</supplierSequence>
        <sequence>7</sequence>
      </additionalInformationREL>
      <approvedEstablishmentPlace>
        <identifier>10063</identifier>
      </approvedEstablishmentPlace>
      <commodity>
        <goodsDescription>goods desc</goodsDescription>
        <lotNumber>lot</lotNumber>
        <productBestBefore>20131101</productBestBefore>
        <value>
          <amount>13</amount>
          <currencyCode>AUD</currencyCode>
        </value>
        <intendedUse>
          <code>AC</code>
          <description>I intend to use it</description>
        </intendedUse>
        <tariffItem>
          <code>3926109001K</code>
          <sequence>1</sequence>
        </tariffItem>
        <constituent>
          <quantity>10</quantity>
          <name>peanuts</name>
        </constituent>
        <dutyTaxFeeRegime>
          <code>AU</code>
          <sequence>1</sequence>
        </dutyTaxFeeRegime>
        <GST>
          <amount>12</amount>
          <currencyCode>AU</currencyCode>
          <sequence>2</sequence>
        </GST>
        <tariffDuty>
          <amount>12</amount>
          <currencyCode>AU</currencyCode>
          <sequence>3</sequence>
        </tariffDuty>
        <grower>
          <name>grower</name>
          <address>
            <city>city</city>
            <countryCode>AD</countryCode>
            <line>grower</line>
            <postcode>jk</postcode>
          </address>
        </grower>
        <itinerary>
          <sequence>1</sequence>
          <countryCode>AU</countryCode>
        </itinerary>
        <itinerary>
          <sequence>2</sequence>
          <countryCode>FI</countryCode>
        </itinerary>
        <itinerary>
          <sequence>3</sequence>
          <countryCode>AF</countryCode>
        </itinerary>
        <manufacturer>
          <name>manufacturer</name>
          <address>
            <city>jkldsj</city>
            <countryCode>PA</countryCode>
            <line>jdskljl</line>
            <postcode>jdklsja</postcode>
          </address>
        </manufacturer>
        <producer>
          <name>producer</name>
          <address>
            <city>dkasjk</city>
            <countryCode>AD</countryCode>
            <line>producer</line>
            <postcode>j</postcode>
          </address>
        </producer>
        <product>
          <identifier>mc1</identifier>
          <commodityIdentifierType>MC</commodityIdentifierType>
        </product>
        <productName>
          <name>brand</name>
          <type>223</type>
        </productName>
        <productCharacteristics>
          <code>Y</code>
          <type>211</type>
        </productCharacteristics>
        <productCharacteristics>
          <code>Y</code>
          <type>61</type>
        </productCharacteristics>
        <source>AU</source>
        <temperature>
          <storageRequirement>
            <quantity>10</quantity>
            <unitOfMeasurement>CEL</unitOfMeasurement>
          </storageRequirement>
          <minimumStorageRequirement>
            <quantity>-2</quantity>
            <unitOfMeasurement>CEL</unitOfMeasurement>
          </minimumStorageRequirement>
        </temperature>
        <transportEquipment>
          <sequence>1</sequence>
          <identifier>ABC128021</identifier>
        </transportEquipment>
      </commodity>
      <examinationPlace>
        <name>Treatment Provider</name>
      </examinationPlace>
      <goodsMeasure>
        <grossWeight>
          <quantity>12</quantity>
          <unitOfMeasurement>KGM</unitOfMeasurement>
        </grossWeight>
        <netNetWeight>
          <quantity>10</quantity>
          <unitOfMeasurement>KGM</unitOfMeasurement>
        </netNetWeight>
        <tariff>
          <quantity>12</quantity>
          <unitOfMeasurement>NCL</unitOfMeasurement>
        </tariff>
      </goodsMeasure>
      <goodsMeasureSupplementary>
        <tariff>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
          <unitOfMeasurement>KGM</unitOfMeasurement>
        </tariff>
      </goodsMeasureSupplementary>
      <origin>
        <countryCode>AU</countryCode>
        <state>NSW</state>
      </origin>
      <packaging>
        <sequence>1</sequence>
        <marksNumbers>marks</marksNumbers>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <type>FI</type>
        <packingMaterialDescription>wood</packingMaterialDescription>
        <volume>
          <quantity>12</quantity>
          <unitOfMeasurement>MTQ</unitOfMeasurement>
        </volume>
      </packaging>
      <packaging>
        <sequence>2</sequence>
        <marksNumbers>marks</marksNumbers>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <type>FI</type>
        <packingMaterialDescription>wood</packingMaterialDescription>
        <volume>
          <quantity>12</quantity>
          <unitOfMeasurement>MTQ</unitOfMeasurement>
        </volume>
      </packaging>
      <packaging>
        <sequence>3</sequence>
        <marksNumbers>marks</marksNumbers>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <type>FI</type>
        <packingMaterialDescription>wood</packingMaterialDescription>
        <volume>
          <quantity>12</quantity>
          <unitOfMeasurement>MTQ</unitOfMeasurement>
        </volume>
      </packaging>
      <packaging>
        <sequence>4</sequence>
        <marksNumbers>marks</marksNumbers>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <type>FI</type>
        <packingMaterialDescription>wood</packingMaterialDescription>
        <volume>
          <quantity>12</quantity>
          <unitOfMeasurement>MTQ</unitOfMeasurement>
        </volume>
      </packaging>
      <commissionsValuation>
        <adjustment>
          <amount>3</amount>
          <currencyCode>AU</currencyCode>
        </adjustment>
        <sequence>3</sequence>
      </commissionsValuation>
      <freightValuation>
        <adjustment>
          <amount>10</amount>
          <currencyCode>AU</currencyCode>
        </adjustment>
        <sequence>1</sequence>
      </freightValuation>
      <insuranceValuation>
        <adjustment>
          <amount>11</amount>
          <currencyCode>AU</currencyCode>
        </adjustment>
        <sequence>2</sequence>
      </insuranceValuation>
      <royaltiesValuation>
        <adjustment>
          <amount>5</amount>
          <currencyCode>AU</currencyCode>
        </adjustment>
        <sequence>4</sequence>
      </royaltiesValuation>
    </governmentAgencyGoodsItem>
    <invoice>
      <identifier>INVOICE1</identifier>
      <incoterms>CPT</incoterms>
      <sequence>1</sequence>
    </invoice>
    <invoice>
      <identifier>INVOICE2</identifier>
      <incoterms>CFR</incoterms>
      <sequence>2</sequence>
    </invoice>
    <deliveryNotificationParty>
      <name>NP1</name>
      <communication>
        <value>SSMAIL</value>
        <type>EM</type>
      </communication>
    </deliveryNotificationParty>
    <seller>
      <name>SELLERNAME</name>
      <address>
        <city>SELLER</city>
        <countryCode>AU</countryCode>
        <line>SELLER</line>
        <postcode>SD</postcode>
      </address>
    </seller>
    <seller>
      <name>SELLER2</name>
      <address>
        <city>city2</city>
        <countryCode>YE</countryCode>
        <line>seller2</line>
        <postcode>jkh</postcode>
      </address>
    </seller>
    <stuffingEstablishment>
      <name>vp1</name>
      <address>
        <city>vp</city>
        <countryCode>KE</countryCode>
        <line>vp1a</line>
        <postcode>00002</postcode>
      </address>
    </stuffingEstablishment>
    <stuffingEstablishment>
      <name>vp2</name>
      <address>
        <city>djskljdklajkl</city>
        <countryCode>LA</countryCode>
        <line>vp2add</line>
        <postcode>999</postcode>
      </address>
    </stuffingEstablishment>
    <supplier>
      <identifier>40038489J</identifier>
      <contact>
        <name>MAGGS</name>
        <communication>
          <value>xyz@gmail.com</value>
          <type>EM</type>
        </communication>
      </contact>
      <sequence>1</sequence>
    </supplier>
    <supplier>
      <identifier>00710842W</identifier>
      <contact>
        <name>maggs2</name>
        <communication>
          <value>phone2</value>
          <type>TE</type>
        </communication>
      </contact>
      <sequence>2</sequence>
    </supplier>
    <warehouse>
      <identifier>20591</identifier>
    </warehouse>
  </goodsShipment>
  <importer>
    <identifier>40063605C</identifier>
    <address>
      <city>IMporterCity</city>
      <countryCode>AT</countryCode>
      <line>importer</line>
      <postcode>2500</postcode>
    </address>
    <contact>
      <name>Maggs</name>
      <communication>
        <value>XYZ@gmail.com</value>
        <type>EM</type>
      </communication>
    </contact>
  </importer>
  <previousDocument>
    <identifier>123456</identifier>
    <type>I51</type>
  </previousDocument>
  <previousDocument>
    <identifier>6987458</identifier>
    <type>I52</type>
  </previousDocument>
  <packaging>
    <sequence>1</sequence>
    <quantity>2</quantity>
    <type>AE</type>
  </packaging>
  <packaging>
    <sequence>2</sequence>
    <quantity>18</quantity>
    <type>PK</type>
  </packaging>
  <packaging>
    <sequence>3</sequence>
    <quantity>29</quantity>
    <type>FI</type>
  </packaging>
  <packaging>
    <sequence>4</sequence>
    <quantity>44</quantity>
    <type>FI</type>
  </packaging>
  <remarks>
    <text>CAUSE IT CAN</text>
    <sequence>2</sequence>
  </remarks>
  <declarant>
    <identifier>40048559D</identifier>
    <communication>
      <value>12398120</value>
      <type>AL</type>
    </communication>
    <communication>
      <value>XYZ@gmail.com</value>
      <type>EM</type>
    </communication>
  </declarant>
  <TSWExtension>
    <MIGVersion>V1.1</MIGVersion>
  </TSWExtension>
</declaration>'
```

Query...

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://xyz.IND/NCCS/v2')
SELECT response.value('(jurisdiction/importDate/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS DATE_OF_IMPORT,
       response.value('(exitDate/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS DATE_OF_EXPORT,
       response.value('(borderTransportMeans/name/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS CRAFT_NAME,
       response.value('(borderTransportMeans/flightNumber/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS FLIGHT_NUMBER,
       response.value('(borderTransportMeans/voyageNumber/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS VOYAGE_NUMBER,
       response.value('(goodsShipment/consignment/loadingLocation/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS PORT_OF_LOADING,
       response.value('(goodsShipment/consignment/unloadingLocation/identifier/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS PORT_OF_DISCHARGE,
       response.value('(goodsShipment/consignment/bill/type/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS BILL_TYPE,
       response.value('(goodsShipment/consignment/bill/identifier/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS BILL_NUMBER,
       response.value('(goodsShipment/consignment/transportEquipment/identifier/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS CONTAINER_NUMBER,
       response.value('(goodsShipment/consignment/transportEquipment/fullness/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS CONTAINER_STATUS,
       response.value('(goodsShipment/consignment/transportEquipment/seal/identifier/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS CONTAINER_SEAL,
       response.value('(goodsShipment/governmentAgencyGoodsItem/packaging/quantity/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS IND_NUMBER_OF_PACKAGES,
       response.value('(goodsShipment/governmentAgencyGoodsItem/packaging/type/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS IND_TYPE_OF_PACKAGES,
       response.value('(packaging/quantity/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS NUMBER_OF_PACKAGES,
       response.value('(packaging/type/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS TYPE_OF_PACKAGES,
       response.value(
           '(goodsShipment/governmentAgencyGoodsItem/goodsMeasure/grossWeight/quantity/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS GROSS_WEIGHT,
       response.value('(goodsShipment/deliveryNotificationParty/identifier/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS GOODSSHIPMENT_DNP_IDENTIFIER,
       response.value('(goodsShipment/deliveryNotificationParty/communication/value/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS GOODSSHIPMENT_DNP_EMAIL,
       response.value('(carrier/name/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS CARRIER_NAME,
       response.value('(goodsShipment/consignment/goodsLocation/identifier/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS LOCATION_OF_GOODS
FROM @xml.nodes('/declaration') xmltable(response);
```

Comment: FYI, *good* use of line breaks and whitespace are mandatory is you want others to be able to read your code easily.

Comment: Also, pet peeve, it's not `;WITH` it's just `WITH`. The semicolon (`;`) is a statement **terminator**; it goes at the end of *all* your statements not the *start* of statements that require the **previous** statement to be properly terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate Bills info as CSV of `type(identifier)`

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://xyz.IND/NCCS/v2')
SELECT response.value('(jurisdiction/importDate/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS DATE_OF_IMPORT,
       ...
       bt.Bills,
       tt.Transp, 
       ...
FROM @xml.nodes('/declaration') xmltable(response)
CROSS APPLY ( 
   SELECT 
        string_agg(
             bt.n.value('(type/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') 
             + '('
             + bt.n.value('(identifier/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)')
             + ')'
          , ',') AS Bills
   FROM xmltable.response.nodes('goodsShipment/consignment/bill') bt(n)
 ) bt        
 CROSS APPLY ( 
    SELECT 
         string_agg(
             tt.n.value('(identifier/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)'), ',') transp
    FROM xmltable.response.nodes('goodsShipment/consignment/transportEquipment') tt(n)
 ) tt;
```

Comment: Hi Serg - Modified the code like `CROSS APPLY ( SELECT string_agg(bt.t.value('(type/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)'), ',') AS Bill_Type,
  string_agg(bt.t.value('(identifier/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)'), ',') AS Bill_Number,
string_agg(bt.t.value('(goodsShipment/consignment/transportEquipment/identifier/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)'), ',') AS Container_Number
   FROM xmltable.response.nodes('goodsShipment/consignment/bill') bt(t) ) bt `. Container_Number return 'NULL' value and If add in separate 'CROSS APPLY' section then return single value rather all with comma separated, Pls advise.

Comment: @SQLHoncho, . 'goodsShipment/consignment/transportEquipment' is a different branch.  Handle it with one more CROSS APPLY similar to `'goodsShipment/consignment/bill'` .

Comment: There are 7 'CROSS APPLY' joins and returning expecting data. However, this is I think static solution SPECIFIC to XML code above and would work If hierarchy of nodes change in the above XML code. I tried to rewrite dynamic solution but having error ` SELECT
string_agg(response.value('(goodsShipment/consignment/bill/type/text())[1]','varchar(50)'),',') as BILL_TYPE,
string_agg(response.value('(goodsShipment/consignment/bill/identifier/text())[1]','varchar(50)'),',') as BILL_NUMBER
FROM @xml.nodes('/declaration') as xmltable(response)`

Comment: Can someone help with request in recent comments? as still struggling with it.